# Is there a way to make the Sql Server FullText engine to stop recognizing numbers as numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have an user input processor that transforms `this search` into `"this" AND "search"`. My processor works great, it breaks the user input into pieces according to what I believe to be `word breakers`, which include punctuation.

The problem is that, while indexing, Sql Server applies a special approach when it comes to numbers.

if you index the following string:

```
12,20.1231,213.23,45,345.234.324.556,234.534.345
```

it will find the following index keys:

```
12
1231
20
213
23,45 (detected decimal separator)
234.534.345 (detected thousand separator)
345.234.324.556 (detected thousand separator)
```

Now, if the user searches for `324` he/she won't find anything, because `324` is contained within the last entry, not in the beggining, so it is not going to be found. I'd like it to stop treating numbers as numbers and just index it the way it does with words.

Is there a way to alter this behavior? without implementing too much code?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you running? SQL 2012 gives me the following results - 12 // 20.1231 // 213.23 // 45,345 // 234 // 324 // 556,234 // 534 // 345 (along with their numeric equivalents which IFTS stores internally with the 'nn' prefix).

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's 2008

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if you say SQL is finding numbers, where it should find strings then casting them as strings seems to be the solution.

```
select cast(345234324556 as nvarchar)
```